# VS Code Dart extension: how do I disable Dart style warnings?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I don't want to name .dart files using "lowercase_with_uderscores". How do I disable this warning in Dart VS Code extension? Moreover, when I rename my file to lowercase, it still shows the same warning each time I make changes to the file. Any idea on how to disable these warnings for good, not just for one file, but for the whole project? I know what's best for me, I'm just trying to code...

This is what I see:
[image]

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Comment: @jamesdlin easier than expected...